# Implementation of `LinkedList`. Removing a specific `Link` (`Node`)

Tags: java

folks, I'm still having troubles with the method `public void deleteLink(String data)` where I need to remove a specified `Link` with the given `String data`. I've implemented it but still it's not working. Could smb please take a look at `deleteLink()` method and see what's wrong? Every other method works fine. Thanks in advance!

```
package LinkedList;

public class Link{

    public Link next;
    private String data;

    public Link(String data){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    public String getData(){
        return this.data;
    }
}

class LinkedList{

    private Link firstLink;

    public LinkedList(){
        this.firstLink = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return (this.firstLink == null);
    }

    public void insert(String data){
        Link newLink = new Link(data);
        newLink.next = firstLink;
        firstLink = newLink;
    }

    public Link deleteFirst(){
        Link deletedOne = null;
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("The list is empty");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            deletedOne = firstLink;
            firstLink = firstLink.next;
        }
        return deletedOne;
    }

    public boolean search(String data){
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("The list is empty");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            Link current = firstLink;
            while(current != null){
                if(current.getData().equals(data)){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    current = current.next;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void deleteLink(String data){
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("The list is empty.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            Link current = firstLink;
            Link previous = firstLink;
            while(current != null){
                if(current.getData().equals(data)){
                    previous = current.next;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayList(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("The list is empty");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            Link current = firstLink;
            while(current != null){
                current.display();
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _it's not working_ is not a useful information, be specific about your problem.

Comment: What is the error you are getting or exception or anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment

```
previous = current.next;
```

doesn't change anything in your linked list.

You should make an assignment such as :

```
previous.next = current.next;
```

This will make the node prior to the removed node point to the node following the removed node.

Of course, you are also not handling the case in which the removed node is the first node. This case should probably be handled separately.

```
public void deleteLink(String data){
    if(isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("The list is empty.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else{
        if (firstLink.getData().equals(data)) {
            firstLink = firstLink.next;
        } else {
            Link current = firstLink.next;
            Link previous = firstLink;
            while(current != null){
                if(current.getData().equals(data)){
                    previous.next = current.next;
                    break;
                } else {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```